# Removing <em> inside shortcode with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

How to remove html elements `<em>` or `</em>` inside `[ref]...[/ref]` code without changing anything else?

**I have:**

```
$string = '[ref]T. Nichols, <em>S. Santana</em>, <em>Clearing waves</em>, <em>(2000.):</em> Lones[/ref]';
$string2 = '[ref]Name, <em>something something</em>, name[/ref]';
```

**I want:**

```
$string = '[ref]T. Nichols, S. Santana, Clearing waves, (2000.): Lones[/ref]';
$string2 = '[ref]Name, something something, name[/ref]';
```

**My try:**

```
$pattern = '/(\[ref\].*)*(?:\<em\>)*(?:\<\/em\>)*(.*\[\/ref\])/'; 
$replacement = '($1)($2)'; 
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Italics can be there multiple times (or none).
The pattern  seems to be working for selecting the shortcode and its contents inside text, the problem is that it doesn't end after the closing `[/ref]`, like you can see in this example http://regexr.com/3ds7p
It is ok to clear all `<em>` and `</em>` inside `[ref][/ref]` but not outside.

Comment: What is the resulting text you want? Is it the tags you want to remove, or the tags and their contents?

Comment: Regular expressions by themselves only perform matching. If you are using a programming language with a regex substitution facility, you'll have to tell us which one. (If yours is not a programming problem, this is the wrong site for your question.)

Comment: The input in your question has mismatched tags. If that's something you need to handle, any approach involving looking for `<em>` and its matching `</em>` is inherently flawed.

Comment: I have tried a few things in the meantime and I have rephrased the question better, I hope. @hvd I have fixed that, although I am not sure if it matters, I need to remove both of them no matter how many times they appear

Comment: I'n not sure this is a job for regular expressions. You probably want to tokenize the string and fix it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Regex for parsing HTML - it's too complex to be reliable.

Try it with DOMDocument, if it is available, or install it otherwise.

But in the examples you are giving, you'd get a way with a simple 
`str_replace(array('<em>', '</em>'), '', $original);` because it's just a oneliner.
If the actual data is so simple, try it..

Otherwise, do something as follows, you could use this code on the body contents of a html page.

```
        $domd = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);//no errors
        $domd->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html); //This is required and very odd IMO. HTML5 is not xml. Oh well..
        foreach ($domd->childNodes as $item)
        {
            if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE) //Remove garbage..
            {
                $domd->removeChild($item);
                break;
            }
        }
        $domd->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // reset original encoding

        $items = $domd->getElementsByTagName("em");
        foreach($items as $emElement)
        {/*@var $emElement DOMElement*/
            /*@var $parent DOMElement*/
            $parent = $emElement->parentNode;
            if(preg_match('*\[ref\](.+)\[/ref\]*', $parent->textContent, $matches))
            {
                //var_dump($matches);
                //test for <em.+
                $parent->textContent = $new_content_maybe_use_preg_replace_callback....; //http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php
            }
        }
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
        $output = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $domd->saveHTML()));
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help but example is simplified, I need to remove <em> inside [ref][/ref], there can be multiple shortcodes inside content and I don't want to remove <em> outside of [ref]. I need to fix search pattern :)

Comment: DOMDocument can help narrowing it down a lot, and thus it might bring better performance.

Comment: I wrote in my question at first but later I have removed it because I believe it caused a confusion. I am trying to modify Wordpress content and for that reason I will be using Search Regex plugin, which needs to have search and replace pattern. Above code is my try to match the search pattern :)

Comment: I see.
Then, by all means try it. It is certainly possible to make it work flawlessly in most (or any) case by regex.

Something like `'*(.+?\[ref\].+?)<em.+?>(.+?)</em>(.+?\[/ref\].+?)*'` and then output all the captures? Or can't you use the captures?

Comment: I can use captures but I can't make the search pattern work. Your code has 3 error and that is fine if I fix them, but still doesn't work http://regexr.com/3ds8h I am thinking about hardcode replacing every occurence of my shortcode manualy...